# Is there a connection between rough set and rough path?

Tags: stochastic-processes, soft-question, definition, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-path-theory

As I understand rough path theory  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path is developed as a method to solve stochastic differenctial equations . Today I came accross the page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_set where a new (to me) concept of rough set is introduced. Before I try to understand the basics of rough set can can anyone give me a quick headstart in understanding if there a is a relation between "rough path" and "rough set"? Can we understand both under one umbrela?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are totally unrelated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got confused by the term "rough differential equation" which is appeared for example in the paper : "Rough Differential Equations in Rough Function Model"  by Yun Wang, Xiaojing Xu,  and Zhiqin Huang . Also "rough differential equation" is mentioned in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.12626.pdf which is related to the solution of differential equation.